# The Pygame nothing jump

Tags: python, pygame

Im working on a Pygame project im getting my player to jump. So give my player  upwards momentum which decreases over time so i get this code.

```
def jump():
    Momentum = -10
    while Momentum > 10:
        player.move_ip(0, Momentum)
        Momentum += 1
```

But the input doesn't register so why and how can I fix it.

Comment: If  you set it to  -10, it will never enter a loop where it has to be greater than 10... Did you mean `< 10`, or what? As a side note, variables in Python should be all lowercase, see [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) for the (widely respected) conventions used when writing Python code.